# XML order by Attribute

Tags: xml

I have googled around and tried to find an answer to this, but none of the solutions seem to work.
I have the following xml schema:

```
<xml>
  <race>
    <particpant time="3.25" name="joe blogs">
    <particpant time="1.15" name="john Doe">
    <particpant time="2.0" name="A random">
  </race>
</xml>
```

I then attempt the following transformation in xslt:

```
<ul>
   <xsl:for-each select="participant">
   <xsl:sort  order="ascending" select="@time"/>
     <li> <xsl:value-of select="@name"/> (<xsl:value-of select="@time"/>)</li>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </ul>
```

The loop works and pulls out each participant, but the sort ordering has a weird effect, it switches positions around but not necessarily ordering them into the correct order.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

BTW The code above is a stripped back version of my code and with dummy data as the actual file is larger and more complex.

Thanks in advance

John

Comment: I know there aren't any formal rules, but most people tend to use child elements for actual data, and only metadata (of which there should be very little) should be stored as attributes (although I'm not sure if changing the structure like this would help or hinder your current problem)

Comment: Chris- thanks, I agree with you, unfortunately I am getting the data from an external source and so have no control over it. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this might be because it is sorting values as though they were strings. Have you tried the following?

```
 <ul>
   <xsl:for-each select="participant">
   <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="ascending" select="@time"/>
     <li> <xsl:value-of select="@name"/> (<xsl:value-of select="@time"/>)</li>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. That was excatly it. I had not seen that 'data-type' when  I had been reading around.